# Does the PayPal Payments Pro/Express Checkout API support sending money to other receivers?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Is it possible to use the "old" (Payments Pro / Express Checkout) PayPal API to send money on someone's behalf to a receiver or group of receivers? I realize this is possible with the Adaptive Payments Pay method, but it doesn't seem to be possible with the other API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Express Checkout supports this.

**For only *sending* funds to multiple receivers with you as the sender**
Though it's only a parallel transaction, not chained, and it may be a little less polished than Adaptive Payments. But it most certainly works.

To send money to multiple receivers with an Express Checkout transaction, simply ensure you're using PAYMENTREQUEST_* variables (e.g., PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT, instead of just 'AMT'), and add 'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=yourfirst@receiver.tld.

Then for the second receiver, use;

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=yoursecond@receiver.tld
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=9.99
```

For the third;

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_2_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=yourthird@receiver.tld
PAYMENTREQUEST_2_AMT=9.99
```

And so and, and so forth. :-)

**For someone else to multiple receivers**
Or if you don't actually hold the funds and you'd wish to do it on behalf of someone else to multiple receivers, you would use the `Permissions API` to get permission from the sender to send money on their behalf, and the sender would then need to be approved for the `MassPay API`.
Given, this is not ideal as not everyone has access to the MassPay API. But it's certainly possible.
If you want to test it out; MassPay is enabled by default on all Premier and Business accounts in the PayPal Sandbox.

Comment: Do *I* (as the app developer) need access to the MassPay api, or does the person on whose behalf I'm sending the money need that functionality enabled on their account?

Comment: Also, what if I just want to send money on behalf of John to Sue (i.e. to one receiver only)?

Comment: Only the person on whose behalf you're calling the API call would need to have MassPay enabled on their account. One-to-one as well as one-to-many is supported with MassPay.

Comment: Thanks Robert. My question is, if I only want to pay one person on their behalf, do they still need to have MassPay enabled? Or would a reguar PayPal account work fine? I won't be able to assume that these people have special PayPal accounts in any way. Thank you.