# PayPal send and receive money

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to recieve payments directly on my web site, so customer enters his credit card information not being redirected to paypal's site. For this purpose i can use Paypal Payments Pro. But also i want to send money to customers by request. And it looks like Paypal Adaptive payments can help me with this.
And now the questions:

1. Is it possible to use Payments Pro to recieve money, and Adaptive Payments to send them at the same time?
2. What permissions do i need to use adaptive payments directly from my web site?
3. If i use DirectPayments and Paypal SDK do i need to create IPN listener to verify transaction details and make it secure or DoDirectPaymentReq response already has all information?
4. Customer can pay me using his credit card number, but can i send money directly to his credit card or only to paypal account?
5. Maybe there are other solutions which can do the same but more efficiently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions.

1. Yes you can use both Website Payments Pro and Adaptive Payments at the same time.  You will need to submit your application on x.com to use Adaptive Payments.
2. Once your Application is submitted/approved, you can start using it.
3. You can use IPN, IPN does not take place until after you perform your DoDirectPayment or Adaptive Payment API call.  You can use IPN to verify all of the data.
4. For sending money directly to a credit card, and not a PayPal account you would need to use the DoNonReferencedCredit API, and you would also need to have PayPal toggle on the feature for your account so that you can perform credits that are not associated with a previous transaction.  You would not be able to issue a payment directly to a credit card with Adaptive Payments.
5. Aside from what you have already mentioned, and what I have mentioned with DoNonReferencedCredit API, the only other way for sending funds would be to use the MassPayment API.

Comment: Thanks for reply PP_MTS_Chad. I'm going to rephrase question about IPN: is it necessary to verify payment's details if i get "success" status from calling SDK method? And one more thing: can i use express checkout instead of adaptive or mass payments as said here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12611244/2047345 ?

Comment: Submitting application is also required to use Payments Pro?

Comment: You do not have to use IPN, it is not required.  The success status from your API call will tell you if the payment completed at the time of the API call.  You wouldn't be able to use Express Checkout to send money.  You could also do it as described in the POST you referenced.  Yes, you will need to submit an application for Website Payments Pro.  You can do that from within your account on www.paypal.com

Comment: Sorry for disturbing but i still have to ask again to be 100% sure and sleep at nights. Getting "success" from sdk method means that money are already (100% guarantee) on my paypal account and i can start processing user order, or i need to check payment details (if paid amount is equal to order amount and etc) to protect from fraud. Is this situation possible: i got "success" from sdk's DoDirectPayment and started processing order and then user got money refund or transaction was reverted? Thanks again.

Comment: PP_MTS_Chad, could you answer, please? it's very important.

Comment: A success will not always mean you got the money.  There are times where the money can be held, or later down the road after you have already received the funds a chargeback can still be filed.  In which case the money can be placed on hold as well and reversed from your account.  This is where IPN will be helpful.